# Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку 403

Tags: c#, webclient

Вчера работал над проектом, всё было нормально. Сегодня при попытке скачать строку со страницы вылетает исключение

> System.Net.WebException: "Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (403) Запрещено."

Код

```
_webClient = new WebClient { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
var devices = _webClient.DownloadString("http://h92761ae.beget.tech/json_devices.php");
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Видимо так поработали, что вам закрыли доступ.

Comment: Вы пытались после этого пройти по ссылке в браузере? Ибо возможно вас заблокировали или ваш ip.

Comment: @Tivyram Конечно, в браузере заходит без проблем

Comment: @Tivyram ip динамический, менял несколько раз, всё одно и то же. Вчера работал с другого компьютера, но на данный момент проверить с него не могу

Comment: ну так браузер шлет кучу других хидеров. И главное, правильный User-Agent

Comment: @vitidev Пробовал подставлять и User-Agent, не помогало. Но до этого же работало и без него

Comment: ну вы же понимаете, что запрос - просто набор хидеров и никакой магии. Посмотрите запрос в браузере и добейтесь его эквивалентности в программе и все

Comment: Плохо подставляли: `curl http://h92761ae.beget.tech/json_devices.php` - 403 Forbidden. `curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0" http://h92761ae.beget.tech/json_devices.php` - нужный вам json

Comment: @defrag Право, пробовал подставлять, правда другой браузер... Ваш ответ помог, благодарю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Иногда веб-серверы фильтруют клиентов (браузеры, программные веб-клиенты, etc) по HTTP-заголовку `User-Agent`. И в зависимости от значения этого заголовка веб-сервер может принят решение о вполне определенном ответе клиенту.

В конкретно этом случае веб-сервер (h92761ae.beget.tech) "не любит" обращения от "не реальных" браузеров, например:

```
curl http://h92761ae.beget.tech/json_devices.php
```

вернет код `403 Forbidden`. Так как `User-Agent` в этом случае был `curl/7.29.0`

Поэтому нам можно попробовать притвориться реальным браузером с User-Agent-ом, например, `Mozilla/5.0`. И это решит данную проблему.

```
WebClient _webClient = new WebClient { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
_webClient.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0";
var devices = _webClient.DownloadString("http://h92761ae.beget.tech/json_devices.php");
Console.WriteLine(devices);
```

Естественно, такой подход не решит проблемы, если вам будет запрещено ходить на этот сервер, например, по ip-адресу. Но это уже не вопрос данной темы.

Comment: Спасибо. Данный подход с _webClient.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0"; хорошо работает.