# WebClient.DownloadFile Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (403) Запрещено

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

Хай!
Я хочу написать установщик, который будет скачивать файлы с Яндекс и Гугл Дисков.
Код:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace FileDownloading
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "https://thumb.cloud.mail.ru/thumb/xw1/test.jpg";
            string path = "E:\\";
            string name = "file.jpg";

            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFile(url, path + name);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Программа возращает исключение с ошибкой 403 от сервера.
В других ответах говорят, что это механизм защиты сервера и нужно прописать webClient.Headers.Add();
Но я новичок и не понимаю как это правильно сделать. Руководствуясь [этим ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797966/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-403/797977#797977) пробовал перед запросом на загрузку добавлять строку:

```
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20190101 Firefox/77.0");
```

Не помогло. Собственно вопрос: как правильно оформить Header`ы, чтобы они работали не только на моём устройстве?

Comment: 1. `WebClient` давно является устаревшим. 2. С чего вы взяли, что облако даст просто так вам прямую ссылку? Попробуйте скачать в браузере, посмотрите, что он дает, попробуйте по этой ссылке скачать еще раз, каков будет результат? Предположу, что аналогичный тому, что видите сейчас через код.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если вы о том, что эта ссылка не ведёт непосредственно на изображение, то на эти грабли я уже наступил и правил ссылку, это вроде как прямая ссылка, в браузере открывается тестовая картинка в новой вкладке. Или нужно получить ссылку, которая сразу создает в браузере загрузку? Что использовать вместо WebClient?

Comment: Нажмите в браузере `Ctrl+Shift+N` (или открыть новое приватное окно), там пройдите по ссылке, что увидите? Наверно "доступа нет", почему нет? Потому что не авторизованы тогда? Почему не авторизованы? Нету Cookie и других данных.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вы правы. Ошибка "NOT/AUTHORIZED". Тогда как правильно сформировать запрос на сервер? upd. Если использовать доступ по ссылке, то файл скачивается битый.

Comment: [Анализируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553) сайт, смотрите от куда он получает данные, как получает, что требует, пробуйте это отправить через Postman или аналог, смотрите на результат, как получите все необходимое, отправляйте все это через C#. Вот небольшой [кусочек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/959093/220553) подобной авторизации яндекса, не факт, что сейчас там все тоже самое, но суть думаю поймете. Ну а вообще, найдите API и используйте его! Также из альтернативы, есть ресурсы, которые генерируют прямые ссылки на облачные файлы, но это такой себе вариант.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ооо, заработало! Воспользовался сервисом для получения прямой ссылки, теперь работает как задумано. Дальше буду разбираться как обходится без него. Отдельная благодарность за ссылки, теперь я знаю что гуглить. Спасибо!